# how to add static lib from other cmake module

Tags: c++, cmake

assuming I have 2 cmake modules

1. `MyStaticLib` which is after compilation will be a static library
2. `Connector` which is a shared lib or executable, and it's should use `MyStaticLib` inside.

So, I want to add `MyStaticLib` inside `Connector` but not simply put `myStaticLib.a + headers` in some folder, but reference `MyStaticLib` module from `Connector`, so when `Connector` compile it will build lib from sources and use it.

What is a proper way to do that in `cmake`?

Comment: `when Connector compile it will **build lib from sources** and use it.` - In `Connector` you may use `add_subdirectory()` which adds source directory of `MyStaticLib`. Alternatively, you may use [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html). Linking with the library compiled depends on approach you use for build it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, `add_subdirectory` with binary path set works as i expected. If you will make it as answer, not comment, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In case of independent projects (MyStaticLib is used by other projects to, has it's own release cycle), you can use:

[find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_library.html):

- Build, test and install `MyStaticLib` into your file system
- add `find_library` into `Connector`'s `CMakeList.txt`

[find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html)

- Similary to above but `MyStaticLib` provides additional information

[ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html)

- In case you want to trigger any additional actions (build, patch) on `MyStaticLib` before usage by `Connector`
- Gives you the most possibilities

In case of dependent projects (MyStaticLib is a subproject of `Connector`), just add it as subdirectory of `Connector` (It must be a subdirectory).

Comment: I wasn't able to use nither find_library nor find_package in my case. I think this directives for already compiled stuff, not for the raw code.

Comment: Seems ExternalProject or add_subdirectory are the solutions.